# SQL Server Databases missing after installing SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017-express

I installed SQL Server 2017 Express as a named Instance alongside my default instance. After rebooting once - both were showing but the I could not connect to SQL Server Express remotely. I then followed the instructions to enable IP on SQL Express using configuration manager and rebooted. Now I can connect remotely but my default instance is showing NO databases!

Also in configuration manager, SQL Server Services does not show any of my instances so that I can check they are running (this was the care even prior to enabling the IP address on the protocol, and when I knew it definitely was running as I could connect to it)

--
Update:
I discovered if I launch SQL Server Configuration Manager 2016 rather than "SQL Server Configuration Manager" I can see all my servers.
SQL Server 2016 appears to be running as is SQL Server Express. There is also a "MSSQLServer" that is stopped - think this may be SQL Server 2012. Not sure at this stage which one had the databases.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for anyone in a similar situation / panic. Do the following.

1. Look to see what other SQL Server configuration mangers are showing up. If you have installed multiple versions over the years chances are you'll see more than one.
2. Try using one of the later ones. You can see the file path too if you need it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017).
3. If you manage to see a list of your database servers, check which are enabled and disabled. I had to disable SQL Server (SQLExpress) first before I could enable SQL Server (MSSQLServer), which in my case referred to SQL Server 2012.
4. If you want to have SQL Server Express running as a named server running alongside your default server, make sure you assign it a different port number (e.g. 1435) in the SQL Server Network Configuration>Protocols for SQL Express>TCP/IPALL section in SQL Server configuration manager.